# Is there a way to create a class with a list of dynamic types?

Tags: c#, types, dynamic, dynamic-typing

I'm trying to create a controller class for my database, but some tables only have one primary key, and some have multiple. And the data type of the primary key differs between some tables.

I would like to create a generic class with a list of dynamic types for the different types of keys

```
public class GenericClass<Model, [Types]<Type>> {
    public GenericClass() {
        foreach(Type t in Types) Console.WriteLine(t);
    }

    public Model Get(Types[0] Id1) {
        return new Model(Id1);
    }
}
```

Where `Types` is a list of types.

Is anything like this possible in C#?

Comment: I think you should outline the specific problem you are trying to solve. You seem to have a solution in mind that goes beyond what C# can do in a type-safe manner, but maybe there is a different approach you're unaware of.

Comment: You might consider using EntityFramework for accessing the database. And even if you do not, it might be useful to see how they model database access, same with other ORMs. Trying to abuse generics for things it is not intended for can easily result in more trouble than benefits.

Comment: Consider using a DataTable class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I was trying to create a class that represented a database table. My tables would sometimes have multiple primary keys with different types, and the lazy coder I am wanted to create a generic class for all PK amounts. I ended up creating a second generic class for my tables with 2 PKs

Comment: That was probably the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you have a `list` of `Type`?

```
List<Type> Types = new List<Type>() { typeof(string), typeof(int) };
foreach (Type t in Types)
        Console.WriteLine(t);
```

result:

```
System.String
System.Int32
```